# Maven build failed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to import a current maven project and the build fails throwing this error.

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): 
Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:80 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.46.209] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Check your Internet connection or maven installation

Answer (score 0):

Check if your network exists proxy and configuration of the your settings.xml (Maven) is correct.

Comment: Internet connection and proxy are fine. Now its shows the error that it cant find tools.jar even though I changed the path to JDk from jre